# Spiltting a character variable from a large dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (17 million respondents) across 165 variables. I have a date variable that is formatted like this:

```
9/16/2009 12:35:00 PM 
9/16/2009 12:54:43 PM 
9/16/2009 1:35:00 PM 
...
```

I am trying to extract the year.
I have tried splitstr, but can't seem to actually get the new matrix or data frame to split into columns. Any help is appreciated!

This is unique from the other extracting date questions in that I need to extract from an entire dataframe of 17million responses.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use `separate` from `tidyr` if we need to `split` by 'Date' and 'Time'

```
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
   separate(DateTime, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep=" ")
```

---

If we need to extract the year, use the `gsub`

```
df2$Year <- gsub(".*/|\\s+.*", "", df2$DateTime)
```

---

Or with `as.POSIXct` as it is 'DateTime'

```
df2$Year <- format(as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), "%Y")
```

Or as @Jaap suggested in the comments

```
strptime(df2$DateTime, format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')$year + 1900
```

The difference between `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` is the `class` of the output object.  With `as.POSIXct`, it has `POSIXct` class, while `strptime` is `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`.  In addition to the above, there are convenience in using either one.  If somebody wants to extract different pieces like 'month', 'year' etc, `strptime` is more convenient.  With `as.POSIXct`, we can wrap `format` to extract the 'month', 'year'.  Also, note that `strptime` class have some clash in using with `dplyr` functions

---

Or use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df2$Year <- year(mdy_hms(df2$DateTime))
```

NOTE: It is better to use Date Time functions for extracting than with string manipulation

Comment: I will try this thanks!

Comment: Every attempt I previously made to use date and time functions were not returning anything, I think because of the AM/PM designation at the end of the "string". The original dataset was a csv originating from a datacollection file.

Comment: An alternative: `strptime('9/16/2009 12:35:00 PM', format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')$year + 1900`

Comment: @Jaap nice. For beginners like me this would be woth to be posted as answer (if it does not already exist).

Comment: @Christoph I showed much more direct methods than something that requires summing with 1900.

Comment: Ok. But I like that it is base R and only one line. Are strptime and as.POSIXct connected?

Comment: @Christoph  `strptime` returns `POSiXlt` class, which may be good for extracting the elements, but it can fail if you work on `dplyr` functions, while `POSIXct` works for all cases

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate, if you include the `strptime` and your comment in your answer! I didn't know that and I think it is important;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the years, you can try this:

```
df <- read.csv(text='Date
9/16/2009 12:35:00 PM 
9/16/2009 12:54:43 PM 
9/16/2009 1:35:00 PM ')

df$year <- as.numeric(substring(as.character(df$Date), 6,9))
df$year
#[1] 2009 2009 2009
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to keep the date in rows, like the original dataset. It has 17million rows, across 165 variables (my list of 3 was just an example of how that variables is formatted). Ultimately, I need to be able to run crosstabs by year on the other variables.

Comment: ok you can then add a column as updated.